# Rooting Xperia Ray (ST18i) with 4.1.B.0587 build

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

I've been trying to root my xperia ray device by following the instruction given in this post. It doesn't seem to work properly for me. Whenever I try to flash with 4.1.A.0.562 kernel it says that my device USB debugging is off even when I've ticked it. Also I've put it onto MSC mode. When I try to put it on flash mode both kernel.sin & loader.sin is grayed out. Below is the log what I get.

```
02/016/2014 02:16:42 - INFO - <- This level is successfully initialized
02/016/2014 02:16:42 - INFO - Flashtool Version 0.9.13.0 built on 2013-06-04 22:50:00
02/016/2014 02:16:48 - INFO - Device disconnected
02/016/2014 02:16:50 - INFO - Selected ST18 / 4.1.A.0.562 / Kernel
02/016/2014 02:16:50 - INFO - Preparing files for flashing
02/016/2014 02:16:50 - INFO - Please connect your device into flashmode.
02/017/2014 02:17:28 - INFO - Device connected with USB debugging off
02/017/2014 02:17:28 - INFO - For 2011 devices line, be sure you are not in MTP mode
02/017/2014 02:17:44 - INFO - Device disconnected
02/017/2014 02:17:47 - INFO - Device connected with USB debugging on
02/017/2014 02:17:47 - INFO - Connected device : SonyEricson Xperia Ray
02/017/2014 02:17:48 - INFO - Installed version of busybox : BusyBox v1.18.5 (2011-07-18 07:43:28 PDT) multi-call binary.
02/017/2014 02:17:48 - INFO - Android version : 4.0.4 / kernel version : 2.6.32.9-perf / Build number : 4.1.B.0.587
02/018/2014 02:18:14 - INFO - Device disconnected
02/018/2014 02:18:31 - INFO - Device connected in flash mode
02/018/2014 02:18:31 - INFO - Opening device for R/W
02/018/2014 02:18:31 - INFO - Reading device information
02/018/2014 02:18:32 - INFO - Phone ready for flashmode operations.
02/018/2014 02:18:32 - INFO - Current device : ST18i - CB511VGBZ7 - 1252-6163_R1I - 1248-9545_4.1.A.0.562 - WORLD-i_4.1.B.0.587
02/018/2014 02:18:32 - INFO - Start Flashing
02/018/2014 02:18:32 - INFO - Processing loader.sin
02/018/2014 02:18:32 - INFO - Checking header
02/018/2014 02:18:32 - INFO - Flashing data
02/018/2014 02:18:37 - INFO - Loader : S1_Loader_Root_773f - Version : R4A066 / Boot version : R9A029 / Bootloader status : ROOTABLE
02/018/2014 02:18:37 - INFO - Disabling final data verification check
02/018/2014 02:18:37 - INFO - Processing kernel.sin
02/018/2014 02:18:37 - INFO - Checking header
02/018/2014 02:18:37 - INFO - Flashing data
02/018/2014 02:18:39 - INFO - Ending flash session
02/018/2014 02:18:39 - INFO - Flashing finished.
02/018/2014 02:18:39 - INFO - Please unplug and start your phone
02/018/2014 02:18:39 - INFO - For flashtool, Unknown Sources and Debugging must be checked in phone settings
02/018/2014 02:18:39 - INFO - Device connected in flash mode
02/018/2014 02:18:55 - INFO - Device disconnected
```

And I've attached a sample screen of what I get. Please advise me what to do.. I'm totally lost... even the log says flashing finished, my current kernel build is in 4.1.A.0.587 but not 4.1.A.0.562.

[image]

Model number: ST18! , Android Version: 4.0.4 , Build number: 4.1.B.0.587

Comment: Did you install the flash drivers from the flashtool installation directory

Answer (score 0):

Do these:

- Download flashtool(I did from 4shared).
- Turn on *Usb Debugging*
- Turn on *Unknown Sources*
- Install flashtool in `C:` drive.
- Extract doomlord's zergrush tool in `C:`.
- Download both the kernels and first paste first one, which is 4.1.a.0.562 in firmware folder of flashtool.
- Switch off phone.
- Start flashtool, select flash icon, select flashmode.
- When window gets open,double click on the kernel name.
- When prompt window open,connect your phone pressing volume down key.
- Make sure that your adb drivers are installed, then flashing will happen.
- Disconnect phone when completed and restart it.
- After 15 second(even Sony logo won't be shown, only backlight), connect phone to system. Wait for the adb drivers to be installed.
- Go to where you extracted your doomlord's tool and double click `runme.bat` file.
- Wait for around five minutes until it says DONE.
- Disconnect phone and remove battery.
- Replace the kernel in flashtool firmware folder with 4.1.b.0.587.
- Open flashtool and click flash icon.
- DoubleClick kernel file then connect phone in flashmode.
- Disconnect phone when flashing completed.
- Disconnect phone and restart it.

Your *Ray* is rooted now. Then install [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) by using CWM `installer.exe` from the same system. Enjoy romz...